# Why does ruby print entire line of input on match

Tags: regex, ruby, command-line

I'm trying to get the ip addresses out of a log file on lines that include the string 'PyMongo'. This is the command I'm executing:

```
ruby -ne "print $1 if /from (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):.*PyMongo/" /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

The output looks like this:

```
2020-04-19T21:09:35.567-0400 I  NETWORK  [conn31491] received client metadata from 123.234.123.234:53016 conn31491: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "CPython 3.5.3.final.0" }
```

I've used the same construct in irb and the code only prints the IP address. Why when run on the command line does it echo the entire input line?

Comment: Try with single quotes, `'print $1 if /from (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):.*PyMongo/'`

Comment: How can I upvote your comment? That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the shell expanding the `$1` variable, you may use the command in *single quotation marks*:

```
ruby -ne 'print $1 if /from (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):.*PyMongo/' /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) and [Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and comments. Just in case anyone else runs into a similar problem, I wanted to post my final solution.

```
ruby -ne 'print "#{$1}\n" if from (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):.*PyMongo/' /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Without the string interpolation what I got was an unending string of digits and dots.

Comment: Ok, I could have used puts instead of print. Same result.